# Changing the color of part of a path while it is being drawn

Tags: android, canvas

I managed to create my own custom path drawing application and it is as follows

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
Context context;
HashMap<Integer,PathWrapper> locToPath=new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<PathWrapper> activePaths=new ArrayList<>();
CoMingleAndroidRuntime<Screenshare> screenRuntime;
boolean inited=false;
Integer myLocation;
public CanvasView(Context context,AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    this.context = context;
}

public void init(CoMingleAndroidRuntime<Screenshare> screenRuntime){
    inited=true;
    this.screenRuntime=screenRuntime;
    this.myLocation=screenRuntime.getLocation();
    addPath(myLocation);
    invalidate();
}

public void addPath(int Location){
    Paint mPaint=new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setAlpha(195);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(50f);
    locToPath.put(Location, new PathWrapper(new Path(), mPaint, Location));
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for(PathWrapper path:activePaths){
        canvas.drawPath(path.path, path.paint);
    }
    invalidate();
}
public void respondActionColorChanged(int R,int G,int B){
    locToPath.get(myLocation).paint.setColor(Color.rgb(R, G, B));
}
public void respondActionColorChanged(int loc,int R,int G,int B){
    locToPath.get(loc).paint.setColor(Color.rgb(R, G, B));
}
public void respondActionDown(final Integer loc, int xTouch,int yTouch){
    activePaths.add(locToPath.get(loc));
    locToPath.get(loc).path.moveTo(xTouch, yTouch);
    locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint = new Point(xTouch, yTouch);
    if(loc==myLocation){
        screenRuntime.getRewriteMachine().addActionDown(xTouch, yTouch);
    }
}
public void respondActionMove(final Integer loc,int xTouch,int yTouch){
    float dx = Math.abs(xTouch - locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.x);
    float dy = Math.abs(yTouch - locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.y);
    if (dx >= 5 || dy >= 5) {
        locToPath.get(loc).path.quadTo(locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.x, locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.y, (xTouch + locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.x) / 2, (yTouch + locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.y) / 2);
        locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint = new Point(xTouch, yTouch);
        if(loc==myLocation){
            screenRuntime.getRewriteMachine().addActionMove(xTouch, yTouch);
        }
    }

}
public void respondActionUp(final Integer loc,int x,int y){
    locToPath.get(loc).path.lineTo(locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.x, locToPath.get(loc).lastPoint.y);

    if(loc==myLocation){
        screenRuntime.getRewriteMachine().addActionUp(x, y);
    }
    activePaths.remove(locToPath.get(loc));
    locToPath.get(loc).path.reset();
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(inited) {
        int xTouch;
        int yTouch;
        xTouch = (int) event.getX(0);
        yTouch = (int) event.getY(0);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                respondActionDown(myLocation,xTouch,yTouch);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                respondActionMove(myLocation, xTouch,yTouch);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                respondActionUp(myLocation, xTouch,yTouch);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code works perfectly for my app (Ignore the location stuff and the runtime and rewriteMachine stuff).

My question is, I would like to have parts of the path be colored differently, the ultimate goal is that I would like only the last few pixels of the path to be visible and the remainder should have an Alpha of 0, such that when the user draws, he only sees the last few pixels of the path which then slowly turns invisible. Is this possible? and if so how would I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean to animate the drawing? You don't need the alpha thing for this. You animate the drawing so that every time you redraw it with whatever at that moment you want to be shown, then redraw it for the next animation frame...

Comment: @Gavriel not quite, The drawing is animated perfectly, as I'm constantly calling invalidate from the onDraw function which causes an infinite onDraw loop, this serves my purpose. My request is that I would like part of the path to have a different color than another part of it, however if I change the paint of the path it changes the color for the whole path, not just one part of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding points to a path, create a list of paths, and every time add a new path to the list that has only a small chunk that starts at the end point of the previous path, and has only one other point (end-point). Then you can draw each path with a different color:

```
Paint mPaint=new Paint();
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//rest of mPaint...
canvas.drawPath(path1, mPaint);

mPaint=new Paint();
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
//rest of mPaint...
canvas.drawPath(path2, mPaint);
```

Note that path1 is different from path2, and more importantly you create a new mPaint for each color. I'm not sure if it would work if you just would call mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE) on the previously created and used paint.

Comment: Yeah, this would be a nice solution if I could split a Path into two paths, in which case I can simply split my Path into many smaller segments and color each as I wished, however I don't think I can split a Path so this wouldn't work. :/ Thanks though.

Comment: then I don't understand what you want. drawPath gets a path and a paint and draws the path with that paint. It's not like painting with a brush that you start with full brush and after 2 meters it gets less color. If you don't break your full path to segments, then how would android guess what "animation" you want? Should the paint be enough for 1m or 2m? When it's getting less, should it be linear or exponential or whatever? If you don't tell all these things, nobody (including android) can guess them

Comment: Apologies if I'm unclear, what I wish to do is draw one path, if the length of the path is 50 pixels or more (as I draw), then the last 50 pixels of the path should only be visible, and the path should fade away right after 50 pixels away from where my finger is touching the screen.

Comment: you'll need to split the path and draw each part of the "fading" with a different color

Comment: That's my problem as there is no "Path.split()" function, you can't split a path into several paths to my knowledge, otherwise like I said previously, your solution would be perfect.

Comment: Where do you create the path? You haven't include that code (unless you mean the `new Path()` ?) You haven't show PathWrapper either. You'll need to do some math, and make the path from small fragments.

Comment: in the addPath function, it creates a new Path there, and the pathWrapper is literally just an object that contains a Path and its Paint object

Comment: the OntouchEvent listener calls the respondActionDown, respondActionUp, respondActionMove functions, and those are where I add the points and do the quading.

Comment: so instead of adding points to a path, create a list of paths, and every time add a new path to the list that has only a small chunk that starts at the end point of the previous path, and has only one other point (end-point)..

Comment: That is indeed one way of doing it. I'll give it a go. Many thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately no, this won't work either, doing this splits up the path not just virtually, but also on the canvas, here is an illustration of my program before and after the changes

http://s16.postimg.org/xo244ygpx/meh.png

Comment: You missed the part "starts at the end point of the previous path" in my answer

Comment: Nope, I didn't in my new code I made sure that it starts exactly at the end point of the previous path, and this was the result at a granular level, when zoomed out it looks like a connected line with tiny white spaces between each path.

Comment: Can you show your updated code? Those white spaces shouldn't be there if you "connected" the start point of the new path to the end-point of the previous

Comment: After trying out many things, I did a variation of what you suggested and it ended up working, thank you so much for your time and effort.